# iOS app crashes after sending the first UIImage

Tags: ios

I'm developing an application for iOS which is sharing its screen with another device through constant flow of screenshot images sent through TCP sockets connection.

Here's the code I'm written so far:

```
    @implementation newClient {
    NSData *data;

    NSInputStream *iStream;
    NSOutputStream *oStream;

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

    BOOL boolean;
}

-(void) connectToServerUsingCFStream:(UIImage *) bitmap {

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       (CFStringRef) @"192.168.1.9",
                                       8080,
                                       &readStream,
                                       &writeStream);

    if (readStream && writeStream) {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream,
                                kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                                kCFBooleanTrue);
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream,
                                 kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                                 kCFBooleanTrue);

        iStream = (NSInputStream *)CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
        [iStream setDelegate:self];
        //[iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
        //                   forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [iStream open];

        oStream = (NSOutputStream *)CFBridgingRelease(writeStream);
        [oStream setDelegate:self];
        [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [oStream open];
       // data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bitmap, 50);
        boolean = YES;
        [self writeToServer:bitmap];
    }
}

- (void) writeToServer:(UIImage *)bitmap {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bitmap, 50);
            int len;
            uint32_t length = (uint32_t)htonl([data length]);
            // Sending out the length of the screenshot image and then the image
            len=[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)&length maxLength:4];
            NSLog(@"len=%d",len);
            len=[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
            NSLog(@"len=%d",len);
            //[oStream write:(const uint8_t *)"/n" maxLength:0];
        }
    });
}
@end
```

When I click the button which is activating this object in sends the first screenshot and then crashes giving me "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xd000000c) in the main.m file of my project.

The server application is running on Android and it's a thread which is constantly running in a loop.

I don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in Xcode and see if you can get the line where the crash is occuring

Comment: It didn't show a line but it stopped crashing. Now after the first length and UIImage are sent I have to click the button to sent new images which are not received on the server though. Only when I close the application or the socket the image on the server is changed.

Comment: I think it's not flushed properly.